# replace images and rebuild all rendered images

Tags: typo3

I've a Image (logo.jpg 800x800) uploaded in the Backend of typo3. This image is used in many different articles. I've placed the image in these articles in many different sizes, sometimes 400x400, 200x200, etc..

So typo has rendered the smaller version of the original 800x800 logo.jpg.

Now I've to replace the logo with a newer version. I thought I can use the function "replace file" in the media backend from typo3. So i used this function and replaced the logo. Now the new file logo.jpg is in the backend, but all articles show the old version.

My question is, is there another way to replace a previously used image? Or is there a way to "restart" the rendering process in typo3 for all images. It looks like, the smaller version of the image are still in the cache or something like that. But clearing the cache doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your TYPO3 version.

prior to 6.0 (and without extension 'dam') each file was copied on each 
usage. so if you have used an image 40 times this image exists in 40 
copies on your server. and any change to the original (modify/delete) 
would change nothing to these copies.
from these copies calculated versions are build. so further 40 images 
could be stored on your server.

the copies are stored, depending on the field they are used in, beyond 
/uploads/...
possible places: /uploads/pics/ /uploads/tx_myext/

the calculated images are stored beyond typo3temp.

to replace one image you need to: remove all calculated versions.
and replace all copies with the changed image.

with 6.0 FAL was introduced and images/files were not copied any longer, 
but referenzes are stored. Also calculated images are stored by hash so 
a resized image can be reused instead of reclculated,
It's just a problem that FAL is not working completely satisfying and a 
lot of work is done to fix this for 6.2. After that a change of an file 
may result in changes in every usage.